# CK-editor: block deletion of span element

Tags: javascript, css, editor, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

I have created a inline widget with refference from [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html)

[image]

I wrote a function to prevent the deletion when user tries to. this works fine when user tries to backspace and delete the span widget.

```
editor.listenTo( editor.editing.view.document, 'delete', event => {
    const ranges = event.currentTarget.selection.getRanges(); // multiple ranges are possible.
    for ( const range of ranges ) { 
        for ( const value of range.getWalker( {
            ignoreElementEnd: true
        } ) ) {
            if ( value.item.is( 'element', 'span' ) ) {
                console.log( value.item );
                event.stop(); // stop deletion when span is found.
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

But when user click the span (select) and press some key, the item get deleted and the **delete** event is not get triggering.

Is there any way i can block the user selecting the span element from CK-editor. I have tried using user-select:none and pointer-events:none option in css. but its still able to select via arrow key. Is there any way to avoid replacing if some user click on the span and try to write something ?